# Python with multiprocess and joblib

Tags: python, joblib, multiprocess

I need help with realizing the parallel method in Python. I tried the multiprocess library and the joblib library, but can't understand how to realize it in my project:

```
while (a > amin and continueFunc == True):
    for i in range(len(population)):
        population[i] = population[i] * F(x0)
        maxpopulation.append(population[i])
    c = (random.uniform(0.75, 0.999))
    a = a * c
    print('\n\nValue after step of cycle')
    print(population)
```

population and maxpopulation are arrays filled with 100 int numbers.
F() is the function that contains a mathematical equation with a var x.

Comment: In order to get an answer, it is advisable to describe what your problem is, and what you have tried to solve it.

Comment: I tried to use multiprocessing and joblib in my code, but I can't finally understand how to use them in the right way